# Java Best Practice: nested getters? or delegates?

Tags: java, android

No doubt this is a n00b question, but I would appreciate guidance or a link.

I am writing an Android game app, which includes plenty of interaction between the Activity  and other classes. In doing so, I'm not sure which is better practice for example for calling a "updatePlayer" method.

Choice A is chained getters, so I might have in myActivity:

```
mGame.getPlayerList().getCurrentPlayer().updateScore(score);
```

Choice B is delegation (hopefully I am using the term correctly):

```
mGame.updateCurrentPlayerScore(score);
```

then in Game:

```
playerList.updateCurrentPlayerScore(score);
```

then in PlayerList:

```
currentPlayer.updateScore(score);
```

I can see the advantage of Choice B because I am then free to change the structure and behavior of playerList and Game, but it sure adds a lot of one-line methods.

Am I thinking corrrectly? Is there a Choice C or D?

Comment: Depends on the case I guess, but I'd go with the choice A. Then just create a local variable in case you are using it more than once.

Comment: If `score` passed in `updateScore` somehow depends or can depend in future on some properties of `currentPlayer` or `playerList`, option B is much better. In option A you disclose implementation details to upper-level classes

Comment: Opus1217, neither approach is explicitly better than the other, but in context you may find that one has advantages. Either approach could result in a "code smell", [Message Chains](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/message-chains) or [Middle Man](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/middle-man). I suggest reading about these code smells and thinking about how they might apply to your situation.

Comment: Thanks David, will do!

Comment: Excellent link - I'll try some of those approaches!

Answer (score 1):

Personally I've always thought coding styles as a matter of opinion. If your coding just for yourself you do what works and is simplest for you. For example in java you name variables in camel case (`intVar`) but in python you use underscores (`int_var`). It wouldn't matter if you used underscores in java and camel case in python in an independent environment.

**However...**

In a place where people must read and understand your code, I'd try to follow conventional coding styles as much as possible just for extra clarity.

For your scenario, what ever floats you boat. Traditionally the getters and setters is the accepted coding style for java.

Extending your classes might also help on not showing your implementation of higher level classes.

Comment: I think they're more interested in what the two approaches do to your structure, dependencies, maintainability, etc. The most readable self-descriptive code in the world could be a nightmare or impossible to maintain or extend. Two things that take priority over "style".

Comment: That is a good point but I believe if you code correctly (Extending, implementing, etc) you shouldn't run into those "nightmares" and your code shouldn't be to difficult to maintain and build off of. There's ways to avoid `classObject.getOtherObj.getOtherObj.objMethod` besides abandoning getter and setter functions @ChiefTwoPencils

Answer (score 1):

There might be situations where delegation will be appropriate, but using chained getters is normally the better way.

Take a look at the following examples:
**Using delegation**

```
class A {
  void a1() {}
  void a2() {}
}

class B {
  A a;
  void b_a1() { a.a1(); }
  void b_a2() { a.a2(); }
  void b1() {}
  void b2() {}
}

class C {
  B b;
  void c_b_a1() { b.b_a1(); }
  void c_b_a2() { b.b_a2(); }
  void c_b1() { b.b1(); }
  void c_b2() { b.b2(); }
}
```

vs. usage of ordinary chained **getters**:

```
class A {
  void a1() {}
  void a2() {}
}

class B {
  A a;
  void b1() {}
  void b2() {}
}

class C {
  B b;
}
```

It's not a general rule for all situations but the second example leads to a cleaner design the classes are not coupled as much as in the first example.

Comment: You've got it backwards. A long chain getters usually increases coupling, not decreases it. `mGame.getPlayerList().getCurrentPlayer().updateScore(score)` makes the relationship between all of these classes mandatory. See the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and the [Message Chain code smell](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/message-chains). Not that you should _always_ use delegation and _never_ use chains, but delegation is generally used to decrease coupling.

Comment: @DavidS Thanks for the interresting links, nevertheless I think you are wrong, because in the delegation case class `C` has to know class `A` - not directly but implicitly because of the method names and changes in `A` will affect `C` so the coupling is higher. If you use chained getters, e.g. `C c = new C(); c.b.a.a1();` (OK no getters but normally you would use them) there is no need for `C` to know `A` that's all outside of the class.

Comment: No matter the names of the classes, the above example in David's comment is "bad". Right off the bat you should notice a model missing. The game should be the controller which makes calls to the model which invokes actions on the game objects. The notion of updating the score of a specific player in the game should be outside the concern of the game as a controller.

Comment: tomse, class C does not need to know about class A. class C is asking class B for a result, and it doesn't know or care how B provides that result. Changing B's implementation should not change its API; you should not need to rename the methods.

Comment: A more clear example would be `player.getDatabase().getScore()` vs. `player.getScore()`. As a client of player, I don't care how the score is retrieved. If I replace the database with a web service, the method will still be named `getScore`.